# failed transaction using flash loan

Tags: remix, flash-loans, flashbots

I, I`m new to flash loan, while i compiled this code trying to use the flash loan but i keep getting "Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction
execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance
(408429)","id":5317042078702738}" i have about 0.04 ETH and 15 USDC plus 15 DAI for gas fee in both Dex.sol for the exchange and flashloanarbitrage.sol to perform the operation here is the code for the dex.sol..
"// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract Dex {
address payable public owner;

```
IERC20 private dai;
IERC20 private usdc;

// exchange rate indexes
uint256 dexARate = 90;
uint256 dexBRate = 100;

// keeps track of individuals' dai balances
mapping(address => uint256) public daiBalances;

// keeps track of individuals' USDC balances
mapping(address => uint256) public usdcBalances;

constructor(address  _daiAddress, address _usdcAddress) {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
    dai = IERC20(_daiAddress);
    usdc = IERC20(_usdcAddress);
}

function depositUSDC(uint256 _amount) external {
    usdcBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
    uint256 allowance = usdc.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
    usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
}

function depositDAI(uint256 _amount) external {
    daiBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
    uint256 allowance = dai.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
    dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
}

function buyDAI() external {
    uint256 daiToReceive = ((usdcBalances[msg.sender] / dexARate) * 100) *
        (10**12);
    dai.transfer(msg.sender, daiToReceive);
}

function sellDAI() external {
    uint256 usdcToReceive = ((daiBalances[msg.sender] * dexBRate) / 100) /
        (10**12);
    usdc.transfer(msg.sender, usdcToReceive);
}

function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
    return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
}

function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(
        msg.sender == owner,
        "Only the contract owner can call this function"
    );
    _;
}

receive() external payable {}
```

}"

the code for the flash loan, "// contracts/FlashLoan.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";
import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";

interface IDex {
function depositUSDC(uint256 _amount) external;

```
function depositDAI(uint256 _amount) external;

function buyDAI() external;

function sellDAI() external;
```

}

contract FlashLoanArbitrage is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
address payable owner;
// Dex contract address
address private dexContractAddress =
0x069d94797715Bcd0fA84f4AfB2C28477607C9Bc9;

```
IERC20 private dai;
IERC20 private usdc;
IDex private dexContract;

constructor(address _addressProvider,address  _daiAddress, address _usdcAddress)
    FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider))
{
    owner = payable(msg.sender);

    dai = IERC20(_daiAddress);
    usdc = IERC20(_usdcAddress);
    dexContract = IDex(dexContractAddress);
}

/**
    This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
 */
function executeOperation(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 premium,
    address initiator,
    bytes calldata params
) external override returns (bool) {
    //
    // This contract now has the funds requested.
    // Your logic goes here.
    //

    // Arbirtage operation
    dexContract.depositUSDC()1000000000; // 1000 USDC
    dexContract.buyDAI();
    dexContract.depositDAI(dai.balanceOf(address(this)));
    dexContract.sellDAI();

    // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
    // the flashloaned amount + premiums.
    // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
    // these amounts.

    // Approve the Pool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
    uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;
    IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);

    return true;
}

function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
    address receiverAddress = address(this);
    address asset = _token;
    uint256 amount = _amount;
    bytes memory params = "";
    uint16 referralCode = 0;

    POOL.flashLoanSimple(
        receiverAddress,
        asset,
        amount,
        params,
        referralCode
    );
}

function approveUSDC(uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
    return usdc.approve(dexContractAddress, _amount);
}

function allowanceUSDC() external view returns (uint256) {
    return usdc.allowance(address(this), dexContractAddress);
}

function approveDAI(uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
    return dai.approve(dexContractAddress, _amount);
}

function allowanceDAI() external view returns (uint256) {
    return dai.allowance(address(this), dexContractAddress);
}

function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
    return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
}

function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(
        msg.sender == owner,
        "Only the contract owner can call this function"
    );
    _;
}

receive() external payable {}
```

}"